# WP8 - This package is using an app name that hasn't been reserved for this app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, xap

I am submitting Windows Phone 8 app to app store, when I click on **Review** And **Submit** I get the Error : `This package is using an app name that hasn't been reserved for this app`

In my `WPAppManifest.xml` file :

Display Name is : GS Value // just an example

Here GS has full form as Global Service, if I use this name in app list screen the text cuts so I have made it as GS Value.

And when I am submitting the app I have reserved the name as `Global Service : Value`.

So my `Display name` in `WPAppManifest.xml` and my `Reserve name`  should be same? And also what is the use of `Package identity name` ?

How can I fix this ?

Comment: I have a WP8 live app. I am submitting a new version of the app.
Before that I want to release(WP8 SL) it for beta testing. Question is in MSDN documentation it says "Make sure that your beta app doesn’t use the same package identity name as a public Windows Phone app". So this means I have to change the app name(Display name) present in the "WMAppManifest" file. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So my Display name in WPAppManifest.xml and my Reserve name should be same?

**R.** Yes. It has to be the same name in your App Manifest Package.

The **Name** field from **Identity** is the name of the package and you can use [DisplayName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn423240.aspx) to display the the name to users.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple issue. You can do like following steps:

- Step 1: right click on your solution that is located on the solution explorer
- Step 2: chose Application tab
- Step 3: type into Assembly name filed the name that you reserved for your application on site dev.windowsphone.com
- Step 4: Run your application once again on simulator
- Step 5: visual would show one error. You needn't consider about this.
- Step 6: click on Build menu and chose Clear....
- Step 7: click on  Build menu and chose Batch Build
- Step 8: tick on both debug and release
- Step 9: press to Build for building your application once again
- Step 10: Now, you resubmit your application with the name that you reserved for your application on site dev.windowsphone.com
  good luck! ^_^ and don't spend a lot of time like me to address this problem!