# This package is using a name that hasn't been reserved for this app. Changed name in AppManifest.xml

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a problem submitting my app package. I have read a similar question that was answered on Stackoverflow but i didn't find it helpful. Whenever i submit the app package, it shows an error:

> this package is using an app name that hasn't been reserved for this app:"the reserved app name"

As asked in the question [WP8 this package is using a name that hasn't been reserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382749/wp8-this-package-is-using-an-app-name-that-hasnt-been-reserved-for-this-app), the answer was to change the app name in the AppManifest.xml to reserved. I have changed my app name to reserved app name but still i get the same error. Can anyone please tell me where else is a possibility of having the app name field OR is there any other procedure of changing the app name?

Comment: I don't think this is a Windows Phone 8 issue. Publishing WP 8 apps doesn't require to reserve app names. Are you targeting WP 8.1 or creating an universal app?

Comment: The error has occurred while submitting WP8 app.The app also targets 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple issue. You can do like following steps:

- Step 1: right click on your solution that is located on the solution explorer
- Step 2: chose Application tab
- Step 3: type into Assembly name filed the name that you reserved for your application on site dev.windowsphone.com
- Step 4: Run your application once again on simulator
- Step 5: visual would show one error. You needn't consider about this.
- Step 6: click on Build menu and chose Clear....
- Step 7: click on Build menu and chose Batch Build
- Step 8: tick on both debug and release
- Step 9: press to Build for building your application once again
- Step 10: Now, you resubmit your application with the name that you reserved for your application on site dev.windowsphone.com 
  good luck! ^_^ and don't spend a lot of time like me to address this problem!

Answer (score 0):

You must build it again and them re-upload .xap file.